# Is it bad practice to Fetch AspNet User directly from DB vs UserManager?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

1. What is advantage of using `userManager.FindByUsernameAsync()` over getting the user directly from DB?
2. Is using UserManager is more secure?
   var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UserManager` is a way to abstract the data layer. By setting up Identity at the container level, you allow the `UserManager` to operate against an `IUserStore`.

For example, you can see that the `UserStore` eventually performs some additional tasks (like loading claims, logins, and roles). It also matches on upper (so the normalized name can be used) and with the current culture - details you would want to handle yourself with direct DB lookups.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/UserStore.cs#L400

Additionally, `UserManager` may be easier for testing, since you don't have to worry about using `InMemory` for Entity Framework:

```cs
var userManager = new Mock<UserManager<User>>(
    Mock.Of<IUserStore<User>>(),
    Mock.Of<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>(),
    Mock.Of<IPasswordHasher<User>>(),
    new List<IUserValidator<User>>(),
    new List<IPasswordValidator<User>>(),
    Mock.Of<ILookupNormalizer>(),
    new IdentityErrorDescriber(),
    Mock.Of<IServiceProvider>(),
    Mock.Of<ILogger<UserManager<User>>>());
```

As with any opinionated library, Identity provides `UserManager` and `RoleManager` as helpful abstractions of the data access that perform many useful tasks conveniently (avoiding the need to inject the database at all). Additionally, if you find yourself needing to perform some user/role related functionality not provided by these managers, it may be a sign of an anti-pattern.

**UPDATE:**

Regarding security: `UserManager` will only be as secure as your database connection set up in the container. In other words, are you encrypting your connection string? Is your communication to the database over a secure connection? All the typical database security questions will remain the same whether you abstract your DB connection inside `UserManager` or inject your DB context directly. But I think secure database access is another question entirely.

There are methods inside `UserManager` that you would certainly want to use for their security implications - specifically around password creation/management (`CheckPasswordAsync`, `AddPasswordAsync`, etc.). But these ultimately depend on the which implementations of `IPasswordHasher` and `IPasswordValidator` are injected into the `UserManager`. Your question seems to be related to a simple data lookup, so this is also a separate question.

Comment: Thanks. followup qq. 2. Is using UserManager is more secure?